# electric-pair for parentheses does not work in latex-mode

Tags: electric-pair-mode

electric pairing for () does not work in latex-mode.

I have included regular parentheses () in my electric-pair-pairs list in .emacs. The list also includes [], {}, and "". However, when editing LaTeX documents, pairing of () does not work, only the other electric pairs.

I already checked the variable electric-pair-pairs when in LaTeX mode, but it is unchanged compared to the .emacs definition.

Here is a snippet of my .emacs dealing with electric-pairing

(electric-pair-mode 1) 
(setq electric-pair-pairs 
    '( 
     (?\" . ?\")
     (?{ . ?})
     (?( . ?))
     (?[ . ?])))

I appreciate any help form you guys.

Ulrich

Emacs 25.1.1 on Debian Stretch

Comment: You do have electric-pair-mode enabled?

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Could you give more details about how you did change the value of `electric-pair-pairs`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far. Here is a snippet of my .emacs dealing with electric-pairing                                                                                                           (electric-pair-mode 1)
(setq electric-pair-pairs
      '(
 (?\" . ?\")
 (?\{ . ?\})
 (?\( . ?\))
 (?\[ . ?\])))

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by adding

```
(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)
```

It ignores the [pairing logic](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html#:%7E:text=Electric%20Pair%20mode%2C%20a%20global,leaving%20point%20between%20the%20two.) that balances out the number of opening and closing delimiters. I can only guess the reason it works is that there is something specific in the tex file that causes a miscalculation of parentheses balancing. Even without the workaround, the problem does not occur in other tex files, e.g. an empty one.